# Deploying 64 bit C# winform app on a 32 bit machine

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a C# winform application using VS 2012 on a 64 bit machine, now I would like to deploy it on a 32 bit machine, but I get the error of the form "... is not a valid win32 application"  whenever I try installing and running the exe file on the 32 bit machine. Please suggest me the best way to get around this situation.  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're compiling for x86 or "Any CPU", the latter being the default. Provided you haven't changed anything, you shouldn't be having any problems.  Are there any libraries (`.dll`) you're deploying as well?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart But then this is not a 64 bit application anymore.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I did try that anyCPU option, in that case it says a .net 4.5 or higher framework needed, but the 32 bit machine is not able to download 4.5 and higher!!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the project was compiled specifically for x64.

Pure .NET projects can and should be compiled to "Any CPU" which means they will run on either x86 and x64.  This is usually the default.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/

Comment: And to go on: if that is not possible (because you somehow need the 64 bit part, maybe you need the memory, or you reference 64 bit native code) then - well guess what: no way. Not possible. The machine needs to be upgraded to 64 bit.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I did try that anyCPU option, in that case it says a .net 4.5 or higher framework needed, but the 32 bit machine is not able to download 4.5 and higher!!